# How to find previous or next element from array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

> I have one form where i am getting `id`.I am getting one array of `ids` from database. I have to check first that current_id is in array or not. for this I am writing below code that is working for me.

```
var arr = [{'id':4},{'id':5},{'id':7},{'id':8},{'id':9}];

   var  current_id = 5;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
        {
            if (arr[i] == current_id) 
            return true;
        }
```

Now Suppose i want to go to previous id of `current_id` or i want to go to next id of `current_id` how to get this kind of data in javascript.

for example:

I am on current_id = 5. and user will click on `previous_button` then it should got to `{'id':4}` . and if user clicks on `next_button` then it should go to `{'id':7}`

If user is already on current_id = 4 and he clicks on `previous_button` it should return false. same for next_button.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Track the index. To go to previous or next, use index-1 or index+1 respectively. Just check if index-1 is negative (<0), then you know you’re at the first element (index==0). Or check if index+1 is equal to array length, which indicates you’re at the end of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this code here:**

**Description:**

1. item index fine and check your current position in the array.
2. display the current index.
3. when prev button click check it's the first item is not an array when isn't condition the decrement one and display the value current item -1.
4. when you click the next the same condition and it last item or not check here and change the current index and display value increment 2.

in the next button click display increment by 2 at a time, because when current index increment on then it shows increment 2, the main reason is the element increase 1 and index contain is 0. so it's increment by 2 at a time.

if you show after the `itemIndex--;` then you increment by one.

```js
var arr = [{'id':4},{'id':5},{'id':7},{'id':8},{'id':9}];
var  current_id = 5;
//find the your current id is exist in the array
var itemIndex = arr.map(function(o) { return o.id; }).indexOf(current_id);
//display the value of index
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = itemIndex+1;
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(itemIndex!=-1 && itemIndex != 0){
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = itemIndex;
    itemIndex--;
  }
});
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(itemIndex!==-1 && arr.length-1 > itemIndex){
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = itemIndex+2;
    itemIndex++;
    /*document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = itemIndex+1;*/
 }
});
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
 <button id="prev">prev</button>
 <button id="next">next</button>
```

**Thank you**

Comment: You can also view the code here : https://github.com/sayed021/practricJavascript/blob/master/pagination.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by various methods.

```
var arr = [{'id':4},{'id':5},{'id':7},{'id':8},{'id':9}], arrids=arr.map(e=>e.id);
var current_id = 5, prev_btn = $("#prev"), next_btn = $("#nex");
prev_btn.click(e=>{ 
  current_id--;
  var prevObj = arr[arrids.indexOf(current_id)] ? arr[arrids.indexOf(current_id)] : null;
  console.log(prevObj);
});
next_btn.click(e=>{
  current_id++;
  var nextObj = arr[arrids.indexOf(current_id)] ? arr[arrids.indexOf(current_id)] : null;
  console.log(nextObj);
})
```

Change this for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a current selected id position in global variable this way :
For e.g.

```
let currentPos = 1;
```

then on click of prevButton you can navigate

> arr[currentPos-1] & change currentPos = currentPos -1;

and same way for nextButton

> arr[currentPos+1] & change currentPos = currentPos + 1;

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following using Jquery `$.each` loop**

```js
var current_id = '';
function Redirect(type)
{
if(current_id=='')
{
current_id=5;
}
var arr = [{'id':4},{'id':5},{'id':7},{'id':8},{'id':9}];    
   $.each(arr,function(i,ID){
   if(ID.id==current_id)
   {
   if(type=='Pre')
   {
     if(i!=0)
     {
      current_id=arr[i-1].id;
            alert('Previous ID is : '+current_id);
            return false;//This Return false is for break "$.each" loop
     }
   } 
   else if(type=='Next')
   {
   if(i!=arr.length-1)
     {
      current_id=arr[i+1].id;
            alert('Next ID is : '+current_id);
            return false;//This Return false is for break "$.each" loop
     }
   }
   }
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="Redirect('Pre')">Previous</button>
<button onclick="Redirect('Next')">Next</button>
```